# Writing a program to reverse the list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a python program to reverse an array and have come up with the following code:

```
lis = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
i = 0
k = 0
while i <= (len(lis)/2):
   for j in lis[::-1]:
      lis[k] == j
k+=1
i+=1
```

But the list is not changed at all. Need Help!
P.S Without using reversed method ofc.

Comment: Can you not just do `lis = lis[::-1]`?

Comment: `lis.reverse()`?

Comment: I think the op is trying to reverse the list algorithmically just to practice.

Comment: The fun thing here is, that the op actually uses a convenience function to reverse the list internally.

Comment: I am trying to do something more than a reverse function.

Comment: yep i am trying to practice this algorithmically, something not just restricted to python functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
lis = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

l1 = lis[::-1]
print(l1)

lis.reverse()
print(lis)
```

To reverse the original order of a list, you can use the reverse() method.